# Как в javafx scene builder заполнять таблицу (TableView) значениями двумерного массива?

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как в javafx scene builder заполнять таблицу (TableView) значениями двумерного массива?

Answer (score 0):

Никак. SceneBuilder предназначен для того, чтобы вы добавляли элементы GUI и видели, что из этого получается. А массив в таблицу нужно заливать программно.

Answer (score 0):

В SceneBuilder никак, это просто редактор сцены. Ты должен создать класс-модель(pojo) для таблицы, создать в контроллере переменную для таблицы и передать свою модель в женегик TableView, так же и с TableColumn, только там уже два женерика, один для модели, второй для типа данных в столбце.

Comment: Пример кода к сожалению дать не могу.